# Archivo más reciente cuyo nombre tiene el formato yyyymmddhhmmss-data-log.csv

Tags: python

tengo un directorio que recibe 5 archivos cada cierto tiempo. Los 5 archivos son copiados en forma simultanea al dir_actual. El nombre de los archivos tiene el formato yyyymmddhhmmss-data-log.csv. Necesito encontrar el archivo más reciente dentro del listado de archivos. Para el ejemplo los 5
archivos son los siguientes:

- 20200707133007-data-log.csv
- 20200707134534-data-log.csv
- 20200707140045-data-log.csv
- 20200707143057-data-log.csv
- 20200707144546-data-log.csv

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import glob

dir_actual = Path.cwd()
files_csv = dir_actual.glob('*.csv')
latest_file = max(files_csv, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

El código anterior me entrega el archivo mas reciente creado en el directorio. El retorno de latst_file para mi ejemplo es 20200707133007-data-log.csv, sin embargo esto dependerá de cual archivo termino de copiarse en último momento. Recordemos que los archivos se copian en forma simultanea pero siempre habrá una pequeña diferencia de tiempo. La respuesta correcta a mi problema debe ser el archivo 20200707144546-data-log.csv, cuyo formato inicial del nombre yyyymmddhhmmss corresponde al archivo mas reciente. Pero como puedo transformar el formato en un objeto tipo fecha y luego obtener el más reciente?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de

```
latest_file = max(files_csv, key=os.path.getctime)
```

que compara por fecha de creación, usa

```
latest_file = max(files_csv)
```

que compara por nombre.

La primera parte del nombre es la fecha-hora, por lo que el orden lexicográfico coincide con el orden horario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta.

Comment: Vaya, modificaste la respuesta inicial para responder como lo hice. OK. Bien.

Comment: @luisfer. Tu respuesta es incompleta: no explicas como obtener la lista de nombres. Es ineficiente, pues requiere extraer los nombres de los archivos y construir en memoria una potencialmente inmensa lista. Mi respuesta es completa, y opera directamente con los `PosixPath` devueltos por el generador: no requiere convertir nada a string ni generar una lista en memoria. El tiempo de respuesta hasta el primer `print`  es mìnimo (usa un generador), mientras que tu soluciòn tiene que esperar hasta leer todo el directorio y convertirlo en lista. Respuestas parecidas, pero no iguales.

Comment: El compañero ya había extraído los nombres. Esa no era su pregunta, pero ps... no hay problema. Tenga sus cinco estrellas 

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes cargados los nombres de tus archivos en una lista, simplemente usa la función `max()`:

```
files = ['20200707133007-data-log.csv', '20200707134534-data-log.csv', 
         '20200707140045-data-log.csv', '20200707143057-data-log.csv',
         '20200707143057-data-log.csv', '20200707144546-data-log.csv']

max(files)

Regresa>>> 20200707144546-data-log.csv
```

Ahhhh ya vi que eso es lo que estás haciendo. Sólo quítale el parámetro extra, no lo necesitas. Todo lo demás está bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta.